# The concentration of Hydrochloric Acid

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many liters of water must be added to $35$ Liters of $89\%$ Hydrochloric Acid Solution to reduce its strength to $75\%$

Answer $6.53$

I tried:

$${ (X\cdot100) + (35 \cdot 0.89) = .75(X+35)}$$

X being the volume of the pure water solution; $X = -19.5$

This usually works... What is different with this problem? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you use 0.89% as .89  ,75% as 0.75 ,it is not wrong when write x by % . or multiply all of them by 100 $$ 100x+(35*89)=75(x+35)\\ x=-19.6$$

Comment: The dissolved substance is same. So new $ X = 35*89./75 == 41.5333$ , needing 6.53 liters to  be added

Answer (score 1):

Okay, you got the right hand side of the equation down. The left side is where we need a little fixing. $35\cdot.89$ is how acidic the solution is.$.75(X+35)$ is how acidic the solution **will be** once the water is added. We need to set these two equal: $$.75(x+35) = 35 \cdot .89$$$$x = 6.5\overline{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

If

- $V$ is your original volume, $35 l$, and
- $X$ is the volume of water you have to add;

... then the volume of $HCl$, the same before and after, is
$$89\% V = 75\% (V + X)$$

So
$$\begin{align}
X &= \left( {89\% \over 75\%} - 1 \right) \, V \\
  &= \left( {89 \over 75} - 1 \right) \, V \\
  &= 6.53333 \, ...
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let us add $x$ litres of pure water(which has $0$ percent acid content).

Acid content without mixing water=$\frac{89}{100}\times 35$ litres

Acid content after after mixing water=$ \frac{75}{100}\times (35+x)$litres

Acid content remains same,as we have not added any acid.we have added pure water.

$\frac{89}{100}\times 35$ litres=$\frac{75}{100}\times (35+x)$

$\frac{89\times 35}{75}=35+x$

$x$=6.5333..